# Cloudformation failed to launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I keep receiving this error(image attched) when i try to launch the cloudformation

```
"ECSAutoScalingGroup": {
        "CreationPolicy": {
          "ResourceSignal": {
            "Timeout": "PT15M"
          }
        },
        "UpdatePolicy": {
          "AutoScalingRollingUpdate": {
            "MaxBatchSize": "1",
            "MinInstancesInService": {
              "Ref": "DesiredCapacity"
            },
            "PauseTime": "PT15M",
            "WaitOnResourceSignals": "true"
          }
        },
        "Properties": {
          "VPCZoneIdentifier": {
            "Ref": "SubnetID"
          },
          "LaunchConfigurationName": {
            "Ref": "ContainerInstances"
          },
          "MinSize": {
            "Ref": "MinSize"
          },
          "MaxSize": {
            "Ref": "MaxSize"
          },
          "DesiredCapacity": {
            "Ref": "DesiredCapacity"
          },
          "Tags": [
            {
              "Key": "Name",
              "Value": {
                "Ref": "Cluster365"
              },
              "PropagateAtLaunch": "true"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
      }
```

ignore below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OqaA.png)
AWS docs: Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling helps you maintain application availability and allows you to dynamically scale your Amazon EC2 capacity up or down automatically according to conditions you define. You can use Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling for fleet management of EC2 instances to help maintain the health and availability of your fleet and ensure that you are running your desired number of Amazon EC2 instances

Answer (score 0):

Your newly launched instance needs to signal to CloudFormation that it succeeded to start using the AWS cli command:

```
aws cloudformation signal-resource --stack-name <stack_name> --status SUCCESS --logical-resource-id ECSAutoScalingGroup --unique-id <current_instance_id> --region <the-region-ex-us-east-1>
```

A good way to do this is to make it part of your Cloud-init script.

Comment: It works but weird i'm including that in the cloud-init like this "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                  "         --stack ",
                  {
                    "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                  },
                  "         --resource ECSAutoScalingGroup ",
                  "         --region ",
                  {
                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                  },

Comment: I suggest you increase the `PauseTime ` to something more confortable for debugging and SSH on the instance. Then run the command manually to see if there's an error. For exemple, maybe the instance role attach to your host doesn't allow the action `cloudformation:SignalResource`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue is with my userdata in LaunchConfig. i'm trying to configure a service which is not installed so the Metadata is terminating in middle with "exitcode 1" which means it is not executing the next step(which sends SUCCESS signal to Autoscaling)

Note: I recommend using files and services section under Config in Metadata section first.